# PHP/Ajax - retorno Ajax não traz quando if ==

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho a página que retorna uma requisição Ajax.

Ao executá-la passando os parâmetros: `grupoCategoria=1&subCat=302` na expressão: `if($dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria] == $_GET[subCat])` é feito o `option` como `slected`.

Nessa página funciona, mas na página que faz a requisição a essa página ela não traz o dado que entra no `if` só o dado do `else`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$grupoCategoria = $_GET['grupoCategoria'];


$sql = "SELECT codigo_categoria,codigo_subcategoria,nome_subcategoria,descricao_subcategoria
FROM Subcategorias WHERE codigo_categoria=$grupoCategoria and codigo_subcategoria in(302,308,309) order by nome_subcategoria ";
$res_Subcategorias = mysql_query($sql, $con_local);
$num_Subcategorias = mysql_num_rows($res_Subcategorias);
if($num_Subcategorias>0){
    echo "<select name='Subcategorias' id='Subcategorias'  >";
        echo "<option value=''>Selecione...</option>";
        for($j=0;$j<$num_Subcategorias;$j++){
            $dados_Subcategorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_Subcategorias);
//          echo "<option value='$dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria]'>".utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias[nome_subcategoria])."</option>";
                if($dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria] == $_GET[subCat]){
                echo "<option selected='selected' value='$dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria]'>".utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias[nome_subcategoria])."-".$dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria]."</option>";
                }
                else{

                    echo "<option value='$dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria]'>".utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias[nome_subcategoria])."-".$dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria]."</option>";
                    }
      }
    echo "</select>";
}






  ?>
```

Comment: Como está seu código js para realizar a chamada assíncrona?

Comment: Olá, da um var_dump($dados_Subcategorias) ou print_r($dados_Subcategorias) e veja se esta trazendo o dados que você espera vir de sua consulta.

Comment: <script>
 function buscarSubCategorias(){
      var grupoCategoria = $('#grupoCategoria').val();
      if(grupoCategoria){
//alert('getSubCategorias.php?grupoCategoria='+grupoCategoria);
        var url = 'getSubCategorias.php?grupoCategoria='+grupoCategoria;
        $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
          $('#checkSubcategorias').html(dataReturn);
        });
   }
    }
</script>

Comment: Luis, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Reverti sua última edição pois aqui não colocamos o título de "encerrado" para informar que nosso problema foi solucionado, e sim marcamos como aceita a resposta que resolveu o nosso problema. Veja mais em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117), aproveite e faça um [tour] pelo site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Código

```
<?php
$grupoCategoria = ($_GET['grupoCategoria'] ? filter_var($_GET['grupoCategoria'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : NULL); 
$subcat = (!empty($_GET['subCat']) ? filter_var($_GET['subCat'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : NULL);

$sql = "SELECT 
         codigo_categoria,codigo_subcategoria,nome_subcategoria,descricao_subcategoria
      FROM Subcategorias 
      WHERE 
         codigo_categoria = {$grupoCategoria} AND 
         codigo_subcategoria in(302,308,309) 
      ORDER BY nome_subcategoria ";

$res_Subcategorias = mysql_query($sql, $con_local);


$html = '';

if(mysql_num_rows($res_Subcategorias)>0){
   $html .= "<select name='Subcategorias' id='Subcategorias'  >";
   $html .= "<option value=''>Selecione...</option>";
   while ($dados_Subcategorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_Subcategorias)){
      //echo "<option value='{$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria']}'>".utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias[nome_subcategoria])."</option>";
      if($dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria'] == $subcat){
            $html .= "<option selected='selected' value='{$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria']}'>".
                        utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias['nome_subcategoria'])."-".$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria'].
                     "</option>";
      } else {

         $html .= "<option value='{$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria']}'>".
                     utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias['nome_subcategoria'])."-".$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria'].
                  "</option>";
      }
   }
    $html .= "</select>";
}

echo $html;
```

## Explicação

Evite possíveis erros:

```
 $grupoCategoria = ($_GET['grupoCategoria'] ? filter_var($_GET['grupoCategoria'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : NULL);
```

Filtre a variável que vai entrar no seu `SELECT`, para evitar SQL Injection:

```
$grupoCategoria = filter_var($_GET['grupoCategoria'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Use chaves nas variáveis contidas em string para ajudar o PHP a identifica-las:

```
codigo_categoria = {$grupoCategoria}
```

**NUNCA deixe o index do array sem aspas, a não ser que seja numérico:**

```
$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria']
$dados_Subcategorias[0]
```

---

## Conclusão:

Seu código possui muitos erros, mas o problema pode não estar nele, talvez seu AJAX não está passando os parâmetros corretamente. Coloque também seu javascript que faz a requisição AJAX na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar aspas nas indexes dos arrays.

`if($dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria'] == $_GET['subCat']){`

Comment: mesmo colocando aspas ele não entra no IF, o mais engraçado que na página que tem o ajax é que ele faz corretamente,
mas na página que chama ele não lista o IF,
tentei assim e deu certo: if($dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria'] == 302){
tentei assim e deu certo: if($dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria] == 302){ será que existe alguma forma para forçar o valor para ser do tipo int?

Comment: Faça um cast. (int)($variavel['valor']).

Comment: $sub = (int)($_GET[subCat]);  $codigo_subcategoria = (int)($dados_Subcategorias[codigo_subcategoria]);  if( $codigo_subcategoria == $sub){    mesmo ele informando que os tipos sao inteiros gettype , ele nao funciona...  tentei usar as funcoes settype, tentei converter para todos os tipos as 2 variaveis, mas nada

Comment: esse combo é bem estilo ao Cidade x Estado, eu preciso alterar um registro, mas quero que já venha selecionado de acordo com os dados do banco.

Comment: eu percebi que a variavel que eu recebo na pagina ajax: $_GET[subCat] ela vem nulla para a pagina que recebe o ajax,
variavelGet NULL